# How to get mood stocks scan to result in a textview?

Tags: ios

I am working with the Moodstocks sdk in an iOS application.  I would like for the following to occur:

1. When a user scans the item, it will then open up a specific textview with information about the item.

How would I go about doing this?  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: it has to be a text view or you just want to display the result information ?

Comment: and what do you mean by `information about the item` ? are you talking about image's name or not only ?

Comment: I would like to display a citation for a book.  Something like this: Isaacson, Walter. Steve Jobs. New York: Simon & Schuster, 2011. Print.

Comment: e.g you could set id of the image = "steve jobs" and display a text according to this id in `didFindResult:`; see my edited answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have indexed your image and implemented `MSScanner` + `MSAutoScannerSession`, in brief, got started with the Moodstocks SDK. Otherwise, let me know and I'll explain to you or you could follow this tutorial: [Getting started with Moodstocks SDK in few steps](https://moodstocks.com/docs/ios/getting-started-small-image-database/).

I'll fix your issue by displaying an `ActionSheet`, which makes more sense in case that you only want to display the recognized image `identifier`.

On a result, `didFindResult:` delegate method is called and you have access to the `MSResult` object which contains the recognized image informations:

```
// set UIActionSheetDelegate protocol

@interface ViewController () <MSAutoScannerSessionDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>

//...

- (void)session:(id)scannerSession didFindResult:(MSResult *)result
{
    // check if result exist
    if (result) {

        // result.string contains your image identifier
        // (e.g "steve jobs" if you have named your image "steve jobs.png")
        NSString *citation;

        if ([[result string] isEqualToString:@"Steve Jobs"]) {
            citation = @"Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life."
                        "Don't be trapped by dogma - which is living with the results of other people's thinking."
                        "Don't let the noise of others' opinions drown out your own inner voice."
                        "And most important, have the courage to follow your heart and intuition.";
        }
        else {
            // other checks .....
        }

        // display an action sheet with the result string
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIActionSheet *asView = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:citation
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [asView showInView:self.view];
        });
    }
}
```

Implement UIAlertViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{
    // handle actions if needed and
    // do not forget to resume the scanner session

    [_scannerSession resumeProcessing];
}
```

Of course, `MSResult` does not only contain the string identifier, you can retrieve a few more properties. [see the doc](https://moodstocks.com/static/doc/ios/Classes/MSResult.html).